# MySQL Query - SUM of COUNT from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have three tables:

- **customers**: *id, name*
- **contracts_jewels**: *id, customer_id, paid, transferred, final_date*
- **contracts_objects**: *id, customer_id, paid, transferred, final_date*

As you see, the structure of the last two tables is the same.
The "*paid*" and the "*transferred*" fields contain the value 0 or 1.

What I need is to make a query which should return all the clients (no matter if they have contracts or not), and for each client:
*id, name, **count_contracts_all**, **count_contracts_active***

where:

- **count_contracts_all** would mean the sum of [SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM
  contracts_jewels WHERE customer_id=3 (for example)] and [SELECT
  COUNT( * ) FROM contracts_objects WHERE customer_id=3 (for example)]
- **count_contracts_active** would mean the sum of [SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM
  contracts_jewels WHERE customer_id=3 AND final_date>=Now() AND paid=0
  AND transferred=0] and [SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM contracts_objects WHERE
  customer_id=3 AND final_date>=Now() AND paid=0 AND transferred=0]

Any idea? Would you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: I think a UNION can help you:
`SELECT field_1[, field_2,…]
FROM table_1[, table_2,…]
UNION [ALL]
SELECT field_a[, field_b,...]
FROM table_a[, table_b,…];`

Answer (score 1):

You can count the contracts separately and then just join them up to the customers:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    COALESCE(oc.active_count,0) + COALESCE(jc.active_count,0) as count_contracts_active,
    COALESCE(oc.total_count,0) + COALESCE(jc.total_count,0) as count_contracts_all
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        customer_id
        COUNT(*) as total_count,
        COUNT(IF(final_date>=Now() AND paid=0 AND transferred=0,1,NULL)) as active_count
    FROM contracts_jewels
    GROUP BY customer_id
) as oc ON oc.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        customer_id
        COUNT(*) as total_count,
        COUNT(IF(final_date>=Now() AND paid=0 AND transferred=0,1,NULL)) as active_count
    FROM contracts_objects
    GROUP BY customer_id
) as jc ON jc.customer_id = c.id
```

Comment: It goes like a charm! Thank you! I am afraid i cannot rate your answer, I am a new user here, but I am very grateful!

Comment: @fortitude23: you can't rate yet, but you can still "accept" the answer if it helped you solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

One fast solution I can think of right now is:

```
SELECT COUNT(`temp_table`.*) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM contracts_jewels WHERE customer_id=3 UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM contracts_objects WHERE customer_id=3) AS `temp_table`
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT(`temp_table`.*) FROM (
SELECT * FROM contracts_jewels WHERE customer_id=3 AND final_date>=Now() AND paid=0 AND transferred=0 UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM contracts_objects WHERE customer_id=3 AND final_date>=Now() AND paid=0 AND transferred=0)  AS `temp_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join each of those tables twice and add their corresponding `COUNT`s in your result:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    (COUNT(cj1.id)+COUNT(co1.id)) AS count_contracts_all,
    (COUNT(cj2.id)+COUNT(co2.id)) AS count_contracts_active
FROM
    customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contracts_jewels cj1 ON c.id = cj1.customer_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contracts_objects co1 ON c.id = co1.customer_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contracts_jewels cj2 ON
        c.id = cj2.id AND
        cj2.final_date >= NOW() AND
        cj2.paid = 0 AND
        cj2.transferred = 0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contracts_object co2 ON
        c.id = co2.id AND
        co2.final_date >= NOW() AND
        co2.paid = 0 AND
        co2.transferred = 0
GROUP BY c.id
```

Note: I haven't run this, but hopefully it sets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

```
SELECT SUM(c) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM `tbl1` where ...
UNION
    SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM tbl2 where ...
UNION
    SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM tbl3 where ...
) al
```